# ListView height (actual)

Tags: android, listview

There is a list adapter:

```
public class timetable_list_adapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
...
}
```

and dynamic added lists:

```
timetable_list_adapter adapter = new timetable_list_adapter(getApplicationContext(), eventList);
week_day_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

list element is TableLayout

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/item_root_table"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="2">
```

In result application height of ListViews is wrong.
I tried to set height:

```
enter code hep = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_root_table); 
p.height = 60 * eventList.size(); // INFO: change it after list_itemre
```

It works, BUT! on the other screen(smaller than mine) lists are too big. What should I do?

Comment: Java classes and variables are usually defined in CamelCase. timetable_list_adapter should be TimetableListAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p.height = 60 * eventList.size();
```

Those are absolute pixels, depending on the density of the screen they will end up the wrong size.

Try this:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);    
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

p.height = 60 * eventList.size() * metrics.density;
```

This will turn the absolute pixels into density independent pixels (dip), so it should be the same physical size on every screen.